# Linq to SQL nested query peculiarities

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

So I posted a question earlier about left joining the result of a query where a group by is used to another table, and it causing extremely inefficient Outer Apply nested within Cross Apply sql.  I didn't get anything useful from the responses (though I do appreciate the effort), so I decided to do some more research.

on Cross Apply & Outer Apply:

> Cross Apply and Outer Apply Operators
>
> These operators are not available in
>   SQL Server 2000. LINQ to SQL tries a
>   series of rewrites to replace them
>   with appropriate joins.
>
> Cross Apply and Outer Apply are
>   generated for relationship
>   navigations. The set of queries for
>   which such rewrites are possible is
>   not well defined. For this reason, the
>   minimal set of queries that is
>   supported for SQL Server 2000 is the
>   set that does not involve relationship
>   navigation.

I won't ask why they though this was a good idea, but I'd like to know if there is a way to force linq to sql into 2000 mode.  That would seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple approach here... if you find yourself having to hammer the LINQ query to get it to play nicely, then: don't play that game.

Since you have `ExecuteQuery<T>` at your disposal, I would just write the TSQL directly, in a way that I can measure, predict and optimise - and use LINQ-to-SQL (or [dapper.net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)) to lift the result into a basic object.

Comment: I've considered that approach.  The problem is that I'm left wondering if I've missed something.  What I'm trying to do doesn't seem that difficult, but I'm not getting what I expect.  I'm wondering if I'm approaching it wrong.